# Catching debugging error message in one single place

Tags: c#, debugging, exception

I am working on a big application that has a lot of levels of hierarchy, and I am getting to a point where I am going nuts about calling logging messages and forgetting about them. 
From time to time while testing I run into exceptions. Now I am forwarding error messages to my main form through interfaces and other ways.

Is there a way to make the application in a case of an exception to always trigger a single method in the main form.

I mean, now I catch the exception and forward it through the interfaces. I would like to be able to ignore this and every time an exception happens, execute automaticly one method in the main form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow the exceptions to bubble up through the application you can use [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx). You *should* allow any exception which you cannot meaningfully handle to bubble up anyway.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        form = new MainForm();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
            new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(form.OnUnhandledException);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: worked fine for me, but the app still crashes. could it be possible for it to crash?